# Step Types in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

When looking at Step Type on AWS EMR:

- Can we specify a UNIX .sh script as an option?
- Can we also run the Spark-shell or is it always a JAR that needs to run with spark-submit?

Comment: You can execute a shell script using the script runner: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-script.html

Comment: You can run spark-shell via ssh to the master. I don't think it makes sense to run as a step.

Comment: @jordanm  I find that hard to follow what you pointed out. So /../../xxx.sh with parameters is possible?

Comment: @jordanm  If so, pls post an answer as I find it hard to follow some of the WAS docs at times. It may well help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command-runner.jar.

An example of s3DistCp proves the point:

- Step type: Custom JAR
- Name*: S3DistCp Step
- JAR location: command-runner.jar
- Arguments: s3-dist-cp --src
  s3://my-tables/incoming/hourly_table --dest /data/input/hourly_table
  --targetSize 10 --groupBy .*/hourly_table/.*(2017-).*/(\d\d)/.*.(log)
- Action of failure:    Continue